# Using CYPHER to find nodes outside a reporting chain

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher

I have included a picture to make this question easier to undestand.

I have a CYPHER query where I start with Manager A and I want to find out:

a) all the staff that :REPORTS_TO them in the reporting chain. Using diagram, answer: B, C, D, B1, B2, B11, D1, D2

b) who the reports :KNOWS who are not in the reporting chain. Using diagram, answer: Z, W, X

I am able to answer a) but not b) without including C, D1 and D2.
Does anyone who how to solve this problem?

I had try to run a query to find the reports and then pipe the results into a second query using the WITH clause but I have been unable to exclude C, D1 and DC

[Object network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jfpc.png)

Comment: Are you looking to return both a) and b) using a single query? Or are you only interested in the results from b), with no need for who is in the reporting chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a query that works, though it only returns the nodes outside the reporting chain. It might be difficult to return both a) and b) in the same query.

First, creating the graph (should match your diagram, except I'm using lowercase):

```
merge (a:Person{name:"a"})
merge (b:Person{name:"b"})
merge (c:Person{name:"c"})
merge (d:Person{name:"d"})
merge (b1:Person{name:"b1"})
merge (b2:Person{name:"b2"})
merge (b11:Person{name:"b11"})
merge (d1:Person{name:"d1"})
merge (d2:Person{name:"d2"})
merge (z:Person{name:"z"})
merge (w:Person{name:"w"})
merge (x:Person{name:"x"})

merge (b)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(a)
merge (c)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(a)
merge (d)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(a)

merge (b1)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(b)
merge (b2)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(b)
merge (b11)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(b1)

merge (d1)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(d)
merge (d2)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(d)

merge (z)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
merge (z)-[:KNOWS]->(b11)

merge (b2)-[:KNOWS]->(w)
merge (b2)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
merge (b2)-[:KNOWS]->(d1)

merge (d1)-[:KNOWS]->(x)

merge (c)-[:KNOWS]->(d2)
```

Now for the query

```
MATCH (:Person{name:"a"})<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(reporter:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(other:Person)
WITH COLLECT(reporter) AS reporters, COLLECT(other) AS others
WITH FILTER (o IN others WHERE NOT o IN reporters) AS outsiders
UNWIND outsiders AS outsider
RETURN DISTINCT outsider
```

This will return people Z, W, and X. There's probably a more elegant solution, but I haven't stumbled on it yet. Maybe it's hiding in plain sight?

Comment: Thx, I shall try that